# How two plot 2 time serieses with 2 sets of tweets data using ts_plot in r?

Tags: r

I've extracted 2 data sets from tweets and I can plot each of them with ts_plot.
However, I want to plot both of them in the same graph to show how many tweets are posted by days.

I've tried to use ggplot to do that but I have no idea which vector should I put in y.
ggplot(df,aes(x = created_at, y = ???) + geom_line())

Which package and code should I use and how to manage the dataframe if I have to use ggplot?

Here is the code that I use ts_plot for each of them.

```
ts_plot(playstation_english, "days") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL, 
    title = "Frequency of #playstation Twitter statuses From Oct 28 to Nov 05",
    subtitle = "Twitter status (tweet) counts aggregated using 1-days intervals",
    caption = "Source: Data collected from Twitter's REST API via rtweet"
  )

ts_plot(xbox_x_english, "days") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) + 
  labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL, 
    title = "Frequency of #xbox Twitter statuses From Oct 28 to Nov 05",
    subtitle = "Twitter status (tweet) counts aggregated using 1-days intervals",
    caption = "Source: Data collected from Twitter's REST API via rtweet"
  )
```

I want to make a graph like that.
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you provide a simple reproducible example showing the structure of your data so it's a little clearer how to solve your problem? A guess is that it seems like you may have to count the number of observations per day for each set of tweets then you would be equal to have y=num and you would need to add a group=set as well. If you provide an example, my answer will be better.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to count them per day and set it back to the dataframe?

Comment: @HanyinXue can you `dput` the data, for counting by days u may use `xbox_x_english  %>% group_by(date) %>% count()`

Comment: I've got an error message says Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')"

Comment: @HanyinXue As above, try just sharing your data as the first step. Try `dput(head(xbox_x_english))` for example. This will include the first 6 rows of data from this data set. Then, edit your question above, and copy/paste the result you get from `dput` there.